# Type 'OverridableComponent<LinkTypeMap<{}, "a">>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am working in a project where I have a component called `ListItemTextStyle` in that component prop type is defined like this

```
import {
  LinkProps,
  ListItemButtonProps,
} from '@mui/material';


type IProps = LinkProps & ListItemButtonProps;

interface ListItemStyleProps extends IProps {
  component?: ReactNode;
  to?: string;
  activeRoot?: boolean;
  activeSub?: boolean;
  subItem?: boolean;
}
```

`component` type is `ReactNode`

This worked fine until we fully upgrade the packages to the latest versions. Including MUI, react, react-scripts and typescript. Now I am getting this error where I pass the `Link` component (MUI) as the component prop.

```
<ListItemStyle component={Link} href={path} target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      {renderContent}
    </ListItemStyle>
```

> Type 'OverridableComponent<LinkTypeMap<{}, "a">>' is not assignable to
> type 'ReactNode'.

Then I tried to add a workaround like this

```
 <ListItemStyle component={Link as ReactNode} href={path} target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      {renderContent}
    </ListItemStyle>
```

Now I am getting a different error

> Conversion of type 'OverridableComponent<LinkTypeMap<{}, "a">>' to
> type 'ReactNode' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently
> overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the
> expression to 'unknown' first.

How do I fix this using typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
component?: ReactNode;
```

If this is the correct type, then you need to change your code so that you pass in an element instead of a component. For example:

```
<ListItemStyle component={<Link />} // ...
```

Alternatively, if `component={Link}` is the correct code, then you need to change the type to:

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
// ...
component?: ComponentType
```